# Showing that a subset of $\Bbb R^3$ defined by an inequality is open

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

I have a set, which I'm pretty sure is open and here is why I think so.

Let $S = ${$(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \colon \frac{e^{x+y^2-z}-1}{x^2+y^2-z^3} > 7$}

Now I know that $(0,0,0)$ can't be in the set, and deduce that

$S = [x^2+y^2-z^3 < 0 \cap e^{x + y^2 - z} - 1 < 7] \cup [x^2+y^2-z^3 > 0 \cap e^{x + y^2 - z} - 1 > 7] $ which is the union of an open set? hence open?

Comment: I don't think that $e^{x+y^2-z}-1<7$ is going to help, as that ignores the value of the denominator....

Comment: I dont have too good an idea of how to show it. I used this method analogously, to no avail it seems.

Comment: Analogously to what? You should note that 0 is special (in that anything times 0 is 0), so techniques that rely on multiplying things across so that they get "absorbed" into a 0 (like solving $(p(x)/q(x)) < 0$ by considering only their signs) won't work for other numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $f : \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R$, $f(x, y, z) = x^2 - y^2 - z^3$.

We have
$$
U = \{(x, y, z) \in \Bbb R^3 : f(x, y, z) \ne 0\} = f^{-1}(\Bbb R - \{0\})
$$

Since $f$ is continuous and $\Bbb R - \{0\}$ is open, it follows that $U$ is open in $\Bbb R^3$.

Define $g : U \to \Bbb R$, $g(x, y, z) = \dfrac{e^{x+y^2-z}-1}{x^2+y^2-z^3}$.

We have
$$
V = \{(x, y, z) \in U : g(x, y, z) > 7\} = g^{-1}((7, \infty)).
$$

By the same reasoning, $V$ is open in $U$. Since $U$ is open in $\Bbb R^3$, it follows that $V$ is open in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: So simple and straight forward... thank you!

Comment: @user65972 Happy to help.